# By using array.push method elements are getting added but it's overriding last object as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm facing an weird issue here every time I am pushing obj to the array arrays length is increasing as expected but the object which I am push at last that is overriding all other object, I am not able to identify my mistake so please help me. Thanks in Advance please check following code.

```
var tablehead = {};   
var experimentsData = [];
var obj = {};
var remoteSheet = response.result.values;

remoteSheet.filter(function(innerArrayItem) {
    if (i == 0) {
        tablehead = innerArrayItem;
        i++;
    } else {    
        $.each(tablehead, function(key, value) {
            obj[value] = innerArrayItem[key];
        });
        experimentsData.push(obj);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `tablehead`, where is `i` defined? A sample of the `remoteSheet` value would help a lot here too. You're also not returning anything within your `filter()¬ handler function, so it's pretty redundant.

Comment: You're using `Array#filter` for...?

Comment: just to filter  "remoteSheet' data

Comment: Then return something.. If you just want to iterate it, use `Array#forEach` instead..

Comment: because you use the same object and it has the same reference in every index....

Comment: No actually you should just store the filter result into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're pushing the *same* object everytime. `obj` is only created once and at each iteration you override data you put in it at the previous iteration.

```
var experimentsData = [];
// var obj = {};  <-- don't define obj here
var remoteSheet = response.result.values;

remoteSheet.filter(function(innerArrayItem) {
    if (i == 0) {
        tablehead = innerArrayItem;
        i++;
    } else {  
        var obj = {} // <-- define it here  
        $.each(tablehead, function(key, value) {
            obj[value] = innerArrayItem[key];
        });
        experimentsData.push(obj);
    }
});
```

Also, `filter` is a bad way of iterating an array, I recommend switching to a basic `for` loop.

Comment: Now everybody uses `Array#filter` to iterate an array.. This is crazy..

Comment: @ganeshsatpute you should accept the answer then - click the checkbox next to the upvote controls.